# Can't display full content in mobile version of website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, mobile-website

I am trying to find errors in the website([www.khushibaby.org](http://www.khushibaby.org)) which is causing it to behave differently for mobile devices (whole header text is not displayed). Can anyone tell me what is causing the problem?

[image]

Comment: The text "our mission is to motivate" etc. is a <h1> inside a <div class="text-area">. The <div> is styled with "width: 650px". On narrow viewports you won't be able to see the entire width of the <div>, obviously.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexP !

Answer (score 0):

You should remove fixed `width` in `.text-area` class.

Suggestion:
Add a `background-color: white;` or any other color  in `.navbar-collapse` class.

It will look better:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But i was talking about the text "Our mission is to motivate ...." that thing is not displayed completely.

Comment: @UtsavShukla Oops, my mistake. Updated my answer.

Comment: @UtsavShukla You are welcome. Keep up the great work!